# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found yet I'm still using wifi. My "Wired" setting is connected but I have no ethernet cord plugged in

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, systemctl

I usually use ethernet for the internet but now I want to use the wifi and I don't have the option, in settings it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". If I remember correctly I used to be able to use wi-fi but I haven't used the VM in like 20ish days so it seems something has changed.

The crazy thing is that I'm getting wireless connection because I can use firefox and browse the web but I'm not connected via ethernet. When I go into settings it shows that wired is connected

When I run `systemctl` I get "network.services---> loaded failed failed ----->    LSB: Bring up/down networking"

Wireless is working fine on the machine outside of oracle VM Virtual box so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

I'm using Fedora 28 through oracle virtualBox.

Could use some help... let me know if there is any output I can screenshot to help with this issue, I'm new to Linux so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Normally a VM is presented with a virtual ethernet adapter even though the host is using a wireless adapter. For example, the operating system in your VM might see an Intel 100 Express Pro adapter, and it would work just fine, even though the hardware is actually something completely different; Even a wireless adapter.

Comment: You should write that as an answer as it is the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual machines use virtual peripheral devices.

When you create a virtual machine, your virtualization hypervisor will expose to the VM a virtual hard drive, a virtual motherboard, a virtual network card and so on...

VirtualBox works by default with [a virtual network card in this list](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html):

- AMD PCNet PCI II (Am79C970A);
- AMD PCNet FAST III (Am79C973, the default);
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM);
- Intel PRO/1000 T Server (82543GC);
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM);
- Paravirtualized network adapter (virtio-net).

To your virtual machine it will be like there's a cable plug into a regular NIC. By default your main ethernet card is NATted with your computer network card (being wifi or ethernet). Your VM will not be aware which underlying technologies is used by the host to connect to a network.

If you want to unplug the virtual cable, you can do it from the settings of your VM in the network items. click on advanced and you will have the ability to "unplug" the virtual cable.